# MongoMapper + Cascade Deletes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongomapper

Does MongoMapper with Identity Map support cascade deletes? It doesn't really seem to, but I could be missing something somewhere in documentation. Consider the following:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  many :comments
end

class Comment
  include MongoMapper::Document
  belongs_to :user
end

user = User.create!
user.comments.create!
user.destroy
```

I would expect `user.destroy` to also cascade to comments -- or at least be able to configure it to do so. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use embedded documents:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  many :comments
end

class Comment
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  belongs_to :user
end

user = User.create!
user.comments.create!
user.destroy
```

This has some cons too though ...

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own into your `User` model:

```
before_destroy :destroy_comments
...
def destroy_comments
  comments.each {|c| c.destroy}
end
```

Which could possibly be abstracted/genericized...